# How does Visual Build (kinook) build c++ projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, continuous-integration, visual-build-professional

The bld file has the sln file specified, but what does it call to build it?  MSDev?  MSBuild?  other?

I want to add some command line params, but I am not sure which executable it calls for unmanaged C++ solutions.

Comment: awesome.  got a tumbleweed badge for this...  I would have deleted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.  For Visual Studio 2002/2003, it always calls devenv.com.  For Visual Studio 2005 and up, it calls msbuild.exe by default, or devenv or vcbuild if specified in the Override field on the Options tab.

> ... the action will **automatically locate the correct devenv.com or
>   msbuild.exe compiler, based on the version of the project or solution
>   being built**.  For Visual Studio 2005 and later and Delphi Prism, this
>   action locates and calls msbuild.exe (installed with the .NET
>   Framework 2.0 or later); for Visual Studio 2002/2003, it invokes the
>   appropriate devenv.com compiler for the specified project or solution
>   version.

http://www.kinook.com/VisBuildPro/Manual/vsnetoptionstab.htm